# Test password for adherence to policy

Tags: beginner, c

I have written a program to test whether a password contains upper-case, digits and a `$`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{

    char pass[20];                      //Declaring the array to store pass
    int i,flag1=0, flag2=0, flag3=0; 


    printf("Please enter a password having a Upper case letter, a number and also a $ sign \n");
    scanf("%s",&pass); 

        {
            for(i=0;i<=strlen(pass);i++) 
            if( isupper(pass[i]) )
            flag1=1;
            else if(isdigit(pass[i]))               //Loop to check if all element in pass has a digit, alpha & '$'
            flag2=1;
            else if(pass[i]=='$')
            flag3=1;
        }
                {
                    if((flag1==1) && (flag2==1) && (flag3==1))      //All condition true
                    {
                    printf("\nNice Password!");
                    }
                    else
                        {
                        printf("\nPassword must contain a upper case letter, a number and a $ sign");  //Something missing
                        }
                }   


            return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your indentation is inconsistent

Comment: With `scanf("%s",&pass);`, I guess code does not allow spaces either.

Comment: @chux how should I counter it?

Comment: BTW, if you can use something newer than C90, at least C99 if not C11. The newer standards allows such nice things as mixing variable-declarations and instructions.

Comment: To counter, use `fgets()` to read a _line_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As a first step, fix the indentation.
2. As a second step, eliminate superfluous blocks, and use a block if a loop / if / else contains anything longer.
3. Next, look at your comments. They just restate the code badly, and are thus worse than useless. Comments should be used to explain *why* something is done, or to express pre- and post-conditions as well as return-values, *if it cannot be done acceptably in code*.
4. Don't abbreviate names more than neccessary to make them useable. Descriptive names are essential to making code self-explaining.
5. Add a space around every binary operator, and after a comma.
6. Avoid over-long lines. Horizontal scrolling, especially combined with vertical scrolling, kills readability.
7. Extract the evaluation of the password into its own function for reusability.
8. Test every function which can fail for failure.
9. Don't read an unknown amount of data into a finite buffer. Buffer-overflows are bad. `scanf` accepts a maximum field length.
10. `scanf` format specifier `%s` expects a `char*`, not a `char[20]*`.
11. Be aware that passing anything but the value of an `unsigned char` or `EOF` to the character-classification-functions `isdigit` and `isupper` is undefined behavior. Cast to `unsigned char`.
12. Make sure to end your output with a newline, or the next prompt in the terminal will be in a weird position.
13. You don't use anything from `<conio.h>` so don't include it.
14. As an aside, don't you also want a lower-case letter?
15. As [chux](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/29485/chux) rightly points out, there's an inherent flaw with that password-security-scheme. Read "*[XKCD #936: Short complex password, or long dictionary passphrase?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/6095/60448)*" for the details.

Applying all that yields:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int validPassword(const char* password) {
    int hasUpper = 0, hasDigit = 0, hasDollar = 0 /*, hasLower = 0*/;
    const unsigned char* p = (const unsigned char*)password;
    for(; *p; ++p) {
        if(isupper(*p))
            hasUpper = 1;
        /*else if(islower(*p))
            hasLower = 1;*/
        else if(isdigit(*p))
            hasDigit = 1;
        else if(*p == '$')
            hasDollar = 1;
    }
    return hasUpper && hasDigit && hasDollar /* && hasLower*/;
}

int main() {
    char password[32];

    puts("Please enter a password having an upper case letter, a number"
        " and also a $ sign:");
    if(scanf("%31s", password) != 1) {
        puts("Could not get the password.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(strlen(password) > 30) {
        puts("Password is too long.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(!validPassword(password)) {
        puts("Password must contain an upper case letter, a number and a $ sign.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    puts("Nice Password!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Except the points 7,9,10 and 11. I understood everything else that you said as I am fairly new to C I am not quite aware of all the syntax that used in the program above, for example: i don't know why you used a static int validPassword(const char* password) or what does a const char* means. But I think looking at your code I think its much more efficient than mine. Also I cant make out how did u integrate the main() function with the static int one.

Comment: Nice review aside from the smallish `password[32]` and lack of space support [...  years of effort, we've successfully trained everyone to use passwords that are hard for humans to remember, but easy for computers to guess.](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/936:_Password_Strength)

Comment: @chux: Yes, an inherent flaw of the whole scheme. Still, I prefer linking [*"XKCD #936: Short complex password, or long dictionary passphrase?"*](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/6095/60448)

Answer (score 2):

You have introduced some weird an IMO unnecessary scope blocks here:

```
    {
        for(i=0;i<=strlen(pass);i++) 
        if( isupper(pass[i]) )
        flag1=1;
        else if(isdigit(pass[i]))               //Loop to check if all element in pass has a digit, alpha & '$'
        flag2=1;
        else if(pass[i]=='$')
        flag3=1;
    }
```

and here:

```
            {
                if((flag1==1) && (flag2==1) && (flag3==1))      //All condition true
                {
                printf("\nNice Password!");
                }
                else
                    {
                    printf("\nPassword must contain a upper case letter, a number and a $ sign");  //Something missing
                    }
            }
```

The code should be reformatted like this probably:

```
        for(i=0;i<=strlen(pass);i++) {
            if( isupper(pass[i]) ) {
                flag1=1;
            }
            else if(isdigit(pass[i])) {               //Loop to check if all element in pass has a digit, alpha & '$'
                flag2=1;
            }
            else if(pass[i]=='$') {
                flag3=1;
            }
            if((flag1==1) && (flag2==1) && (flag3==1)) {     //All condition true
                printf("\nNice Password!");
            }
            else {
                printf("\nPassword must contain a upper case letter, a number and a $ sign");  //Something missing
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Your elimination of superfluous blocks changed the structure.

Comment: but if i will put this code :  if((flag1==1) && (flag2==1) && (flag3==1)) {     //All condition true
                printf("\nNice Password!");
            }
            else {
                printf("\nPassword must contain a upper case letter, a number and a $ sign");  //Something missing
            }   

like you said wouldn't it be included in the loop?

Comment: @Deduplicator I didn't understand what you mean, can you say it in simple words I am new to programming.

Comment: @SrijanSingh I believe you wanted to use a block scope within the loop rather than a surrounding one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but including it in the loop will make it print the printf statement multiple times, isn't it?

Comment: @SrijanSingh Well ,if you don't want that, simply put that out of the loop's scope and surround the whole stuff with another one?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah seems right that way, Thanks buddy! Anything else that I should keep in mind when writing a program?

Comment: @SrijanSingh _"Anything else that I should keep in mind when writing a program?"_ Whatever you do, keep your pants on!